# Spartacus Category Routing

Tags: angular, routes, spartacus-storefront

I examine `Spartacus` documents, we can edit the `url` for the `products` as we want.

```
ConfigModule.withConfig({
  routing: {
    routes: {
      product: {
        paths: [
          'electronics/my-categories/p/:productCode/'
        ]
      },
    }
  }
})
```

I want to do a similar url editing for `categories` but I don't see any changes.

```
category: {
        paths: [
          'categories/my-categories/..'
        ]
      }
```

The `URL` is still like **this**

http://localhost:4200/electronics-spa/en/USD/Open-Catalogue/Cameras/Film-Cameras/c/574

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi! Did you try to open the page by direct "custom" category URL ? Does it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL `http://localhost:4200/electronics-spa/en/USD/Open-Catalogue/Cameras/Film-Cameras/c/574` likely comes from the CMS-driven links. They are not controlled by Spartacus configuration. To change the navigation links, you need to amend them in your CMS backoffice system.

By default, both types of category links are recognized:

- the ones controlled by Spartacus configuration
- the CMS-driven ones (spartacus recognizes them thanks to pattern `**/c/:categoryCode` by convention).

You can customize what is recognized as a valid product/category URL though. See:

- docs: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/adding-and-customizing-routes/#avoiding-static-url-segments-in-the-product-page-url-advanced
- video: https://enable.cx.sap.com/media/Custom+Angular+URL+Matchers+in+Spartacus+Storefront+-+SAP+Commerce+Cloud/1_hhjqkiuy